# When I execute method `to`, method `from` fails in GSAP

Tags: gsap

I modified the official `splitText` example so that the text is not displayed by default, when the `show` button is clicked the text is displayed, when the `disappear` button is clicked the text disappears, then when I click the `show` button again the text is not displayed, I want to click the `disappear` button and then click the `show` button to display the text again, how should I modify it? Thanks

[online demo](https://codepen.io/dxcqcv/pen/qBJoqJp)